# How to listen Zoom in/out event of WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I want to hide/show navigationBar of a `UINavigationController` when the `WKWebView` zooms out/in.

To hide or show a `UINavigationBar` is quite easy as follows:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
```

But the problem is that I don't know where to put the code.

I am thinking to intercept the zoom event of `WKWebView`. May be there are other ways, any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every `WKWebView` has a `scrollView` property which allows you to access the `UIScrollView` part of the the web view.  You can use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` method, `scrollViewDidScroll` to get callbacks on when the web view scrolls.

First, set the scroll view delegate:

```
let webView = WKWebView(...)
webView.scrollView.delegate = self
```

Then, implement the delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll` and add the logic to hide and show the navigation bar:

```
extension YourClass: UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // you can use the position of the scrollView to show and hide your nav bar here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to achieve it:

```
self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

iOS 8.0 gives UINavigationController a simple property that masks some complex behavior. If you set hidesBarsOnSwipe to be true for any UINavigationController, then iOS automatically adds a tap gesture recognizer to your view to handle hiding (and showing) the navigation bar as needed. This means you can mimic Safari's navigation bar behavior in just one line of code.